# Insert search word into title of search result page?

Tags: joomla, seo, joomla2.5

I want to modify the title of search result page and insert the search word into the title to avoid duplicate title mistake in Google.

Like this: http://imgur.com/6dcmlrA

Please help me.

thanks

Comment: I would say that this should be done more to help people than Google. I'm not sure that Google actually indexes different search pages, since that would require them randomly searching your site through the search engine. That is unless you link to search pages?

Comment: @David Fritsch: On my site, I use the keywords of articles as tags: http://quangcaolacviet.com/bien-quang-cao/6-bien-hop-den-light-box.html . So I link to the search result page for each keyword/tag.

Comment: Then this is a good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following properties:

- $this->searchword
- $this->origkeyword
- $this->searchphrase
- $this->searchareas

They contain the search parameters.

To set the title, you use `$this->document->setTitle($title);`, where `$title` is your string.

Comment: thank @Bakual. You save my day. I also works well in my custom template.